# discord.js message.member always seems to be null

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am using Discord.js and have a long running Discord bot that suddenly stopped working recently due to the message.member object always being null.

For example:

```
if (message.channel.name.endsWith("channel-name")) {
  if (message.member.roles.has(admin_role)) {
    // do work
  }
}
```

This is always yielding: TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of null

This error is also happening everywhere in our codebase where we look at message.member.

Even console logging the message object completely, we see for certain that the member property is null.

Is there some error going on with Discord.js? Has something changed?

Answer (score 1):

The answer here was my npm packages were outdated and required an update. Afterwards, everything started working again.

Comment: If you found the solution to your problem, be sure to accept your answer by clicking the check mark next to your answer to let others know that you've found a solution, especially if you found it yourself!

Comment: For myself, I installed npm and the updated with `npm update`. I suspect that discord js was the package needing update, but that's just a guess.