# Discord.js "message.member" returns null even when my packages are upto date

Tags: discord, discord.js

I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573006/discord-js-message-member-always-seems-to-be-null) but it did't seems working for me.

```
console.log(message.member)
```

I'm using Discord.js V13. accurate version: 13.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `message.member` is null, it means the message comes from a private message, not in a server. Or, that you don't have the necessary intents enabled :

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({
// Add this :
  intents : ['GUILDS','GUILD_MEMBERS','GUILD_MESSAGES']
})
```

Comment: Thank you, I was missing "GUILD_MESSAGES" intent